# TornadoFX unresolved JavaFx

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, kotlin, tornadofx, javafx-11

I wanted to create a new project that should be a desktop application. For this purpose, I have selected Kotlin language and TornadoFX framework. I have installed the `TornadoFX`plugin and created a new T`tornadofx-gradle-project`. The base setup made by Intellij was successful but I have encountered a problem. When I wanted to run the generated project it failed. The project cannot resolve the java fx. I have dug through the web and found nothing that would fix the problem. The error log that I receive after the failed build is:

[image: error log]

HAs anyone faces the same issue? How can I get rid of it?

I have installed the JDK 11 and set it up to the build config and I still receive the problem:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openjfx/gradle/JavaFXPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

[image]

Is there a change that I have missed something in the middle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are running the TornadoFX project with Java 11 or 12.

It also looks like the TornadoFX [plugin](https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx-idea-plugin) is intended for Java 1.8, but it is not advised what to do with Java 11+.

Since Java 11, JavaFX is no longer part of the JDK.

You can read all about getting JavaFX as a third party dependency into your project here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/, and since you are using Gradle, this section will be helpful: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#gradle.

I've just installed the Tornado plugin, and created a project, using JDK 12.0.1. I've also updated the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to use Gradle 5.3-bin as the default 4.4 doesn't work with Java 11+.

If I run it, I get the same errors:

```
e: /.../src/main/kotlin/com/example/demo/app/Styles.kt: (3, 8): \
Unresolved reference: javafx
e: /.../src/main/kotlin/com/example/demo/app/Styles.kt: (18, 13): \
Cannot access class 'javafx.scene.text.FontWeight'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies
...
```

Basically these errors indicate that JavaFX is not found. The Tornado plugin wasn't expecting this.

**Solution**

There is an easy solution to make this work: add the JavaFX gradle plugin to the build, so it deals with the JavaFX part.

According to the plugin's [repository](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin), all you need to do is edit the build.gradle file and add:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.2.60"
    ext.tornadofx_version = "1.7.17"
    ext.junit_version = "5.1.0"

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            setUrl("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.1.0"
// Add JavaFX plugin:
        classpath 'org.openjfx:javafx-plugin:0.0.7'
    }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"
apply plugin: "application"
apply plugin: "org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin"
// Apply JavaFX plugin:
apply plugin: 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin'

// Add the JavaFX version and required modules:
javafx {
    version = "12.0.1"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}
...
```

And this is it, refresh your project, the IDE should recognize all the JavaFX classes.

If you modify the default `MainView.kt` like:

```
class MainView : View("Hello TornadoFX \n with JavaFX " 
        + System.getProperty("javafx.version")) {
    override val root = hbox {
        label(title) {
            addClass(Styles.heading)
        }
    }
}
```

you should be able to run it:

[image]

Comment: Hey. This helped. Unfortunately, I have run into another error. `org/openjfx/gradle/JavaFXPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0` is there a chance that you know how to fix this?

Comment: You need to use JDK 11 or 12, the error indicates that you are using JDK 1.8.

Comment: I have installed the JDK 11 and set it up as a runtime in the build configuration of the Intelij IDE. I have no idea where to go now :(. The screenshot is applied to the main question post.

Comment: Make sure your project is set to JDK 11: Project Structure -> project (SDK and language level), and also the gradle settings -> JVM is set to JDK 11. Then refresh the gradle project.

Comment: Thank you very much for help

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for those who wish to use Gradle Kotlin DSL.

An example of minimal `build.gradle.kts`:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.0-rc"
    application
    id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin") version "0.0.9"
}

application { mainClassName = "com.example.MyApp" }


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven("https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap")
}

dependencies {
    // Kotlin standard library
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    // TornadoFX dependency
    implementation("no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.20")
}

// JavaJX module to include
javafx { modules = listOf("javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml", "javafx.graphics") }

// Set Kotlin/JVM target versions
tasks.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11" // or higher
    kotlinOptions.languageVersion = "1.4"
}

// Be sure to use lates Gradle version
tasks.named<Wrapper>("wrapper") { gradleVersion = "6.6" }
```

For a full working example, check out GitHub [repository](https://github.com/slavaatsig/kotlin-tornadofx-jvm11)

Please note that it also works with JDK 13 and 14

Answer (score 0):

i'm recieved this error when download Kodein-Samples and trying to run tornadofx sample under Java11/12 and JavaFX13.

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openjfx/gradle/JavaFXPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

The solution was is quite simple: i'm only comment another modules in settings.gradle (because the error occurred in some other module). Unfortunately, after the launch the application generates an error when trying to edit the record. I haven't dealt with it yet.
so my build.gradle.kts looks like this:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

val kodeinVersion: String by rootProject.extra

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm")
    application
    id("org.openjfx.javafxplugin") version "0.0.8"
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven(url = "https://dl.bintray.com/kodein-framework/Kodein-DI/")
}

application {
    mainClassName = "org.kodein.samples.di.tornadofx.KodeinApplication"
}

javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = mutableListOf("javafx.controls", "javafx.fxml", "javafx.base", "javafx.media")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation("no.tornado:tornadofx:1.7.19")

    implementation("org.kodein.di:kodein-di-generic-jvm:$kodeinVersion")
    implementation("org.kodein.di:kodein-di-conf:$kodeinVersion")
    implementation("org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-tornadofx-jvm:$kodeinVersion")
}
```

i made fork for this example with changes: https://github.com/ibelozor/Kodein-Samples